Scroll to needed position when user popups Spinner's list
Notice: I do NOT want to select the item, I just want to scroll to that item and let user to select.
I have an application for android. This application contains a Spinner. The spinner has quite many items. I want this - when user popups the spinner it should be scrolled automatically to some specific position in the list. How to do this?

I'm pretty sure there's no way to do that with the public API. Spinner is basically a wrapper around a custom AlertDialog or ListPopupWindow, depending on its mode, and there's no way to get at the ListView in either, so the only thing available is setSelection(). If you do really need that feature, it might be easier to put something together from a TextView and your own AlertDialog or ListPopupWindow, where you could control the ListView directly yourself. Otherwise, you're probably looking at reflection – which would be better on AppCompatSpinner – or possibly forking.

seems that you want a initial value after set adapter, try:
spinner.setSelection(specificPosition)

or
spinner.setSelection(specificPosition, true) // with animate


No. I do not want to select any item. I just want to scroll the list to item.
